# How can add an form below post editor of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add a custom form below post editor of wordpress. I have a custom post type cottage here I can add cottage and its details like title,details,add custom fields by types plugin,featured image etc.

Now I need to create a custom form below the post editor in which I have to add a custom form. How to do this ?

I also need to know how can I display extra div and some data below the post editor  in admin panel.For example i need to display a images some static words in a specific page below the post editor or any position inside the page view in admin panel  i.e

```
 if(get_the_ID()==24)
         {
             CUSTOM html
       }
```

Please help and in case possible provide any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install Advanced Custom fields plugin (ACF) https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Here you can add custom fields and select on what pages, posts, post types they will be shown.